# Canvas android question regarding endpoints

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

Why does on draw sometimes what pixels like:

```
            xAxis = new RectF(0, 0, 400, 400);
```

Other times it takes float points like:

```
    xAxis = new RectF(0.29f, 0.24f, 0.55f, 0.76f);
```

How do I know which one to use and when? because I was using the float point version then all of a sudden the lines disappeared and it took me a while to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use just Rect instead of RectF?  RectF is for floating point, Rect is for integers

Comment: I want to use RectF so I can get a percentage of the screen so it can resize properly, IE drawing axis lines that spread out over a higher pixel density instead of staying close together.

Comment: You can compute axis step by getting proper coordinates with getDrawingRect() of your Layout. I used that in a multi-panel layout to auto fit  for 4, 6 and 8 panels in every screen type/resolutions.

Comment: thanks! that way it won't get fat on the higher pixel side too, wonder why I didn't think of that....